# Regex ensure that there's only one blank line(2 newlines) after each section ends and another section begins in any Text-INI file

Tags: regex, pcre, text-editor, text-processing

As I have mentioned in Question title, I have following INI file, which contains umpteen number of sections and each section containing umpteen lines:

```
....
....   (many more section up above)
....
[Zynga Games *]
Section=Games
DetectFile=%LocalAppData%\Zynga
FileKey1=%LocalAppData%\Zynga\Logs|*.*|RECURSE

[*Microsoft Windows Game Statistics]
LangSecRef=3025
DetectOS=6.0
DetectFile=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\
Default=False
FileKey1=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Chess Titans\|chesstitans.xml
FileKey2=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Freecell\|freecell.xml
FileKey3=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Hearts\|hearts.xml
FileKey4=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Mahjong Titans\|mahjong titans.xml
FileKey8=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Minesweeper\|minesweeper.xml
FileKey5=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Purble Place\|purble place.xml
FileKey6=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Solitaire\|solitaire.xml
FileKey7=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Spider Solitaire\|spider solitaire.xml

[iMVU Cache]

LangSecRef=3022

DectectFile=%appdata%\IMVUClient\IMVUClient.exe

Default=False

FileKey1=%appdata%\IMVU\cache\|*.*|REMOVESELF|

FileKey2=%appdata%\IMVU\AssetCache\|*.*|REMOVESELF|

FileKey3=%appdata%\IMVU\PixmapCache\|*.*|REMOVESELF|
....
....        (many more could be below too...)
....
```

Now as you can see when I pasted code from external Google search pages, sometimes these codes are with extra newlines, which occur after each line, which kinda breaks the pattern and/or format of INI files which ensure **there's 2 newlines between one section's ending and another one's beginning and only one newline after each section's children lines**.

Now I know that with Regex we can replace multiple newlines into single newline by *Find:`\n\n*`* and *Replace with: `\r\n`* in any Text editor that supports PCRE Regex, but when there's extra newlines spread across multiple/all children lines of a section, then how can I text process it to ensure there's only one newline between each children lines of a section and 2 newlines between consecutive sections across the whole file ?

So after the Regex replace text processing the final output is this:

```
....
....   (many more section up above)
....
[Zynga Games *]
Section=Games
DetectFile=%LocalAppData%\Zynga
FileKey1=%LocalAppData%\Zynga\Logs|*.*|RECURSE

[*Microsoft Windows Game Statistics]
LangSecRef=3025
DetectOS=6.0
DetectFile=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\
Default=False
FileKey1=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Chess Titans\|chesstitans.xml
FileKey2=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Freecell\|freecell.xml
FileKey3=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Hearts\|hearts.xml
FileKey4=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Mahjong Titans\|mahjong titans.xml
FileKey8=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Minesweeper\|minesweeper.xml
FileKey5=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Purble Place\|purble place.xml
FileKey6=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Solitaire\|solitaire.xml
FileKey7=%localappdata%\Microsoft Games\Spider Solitaire\|spider solitaire.xml

[iMVU Cache]
LangSecRef=3022
DectectFile=%appdata%\IMVUClient\IMVUClient.exe
Default=False
FileKey1=%appdata%\IMVU\cache\|*.*|REMOVESELF|
FileKey2=%appdata%\IMVU\AssetCache\|*.*|REMOVESELF|
FileKey3=%appdata%\IMVU\PixmapCache\|*.*|REMOVESELF|
....
....        (many more could be below too...)
....
```

Am not so well-versed in Regex so any help is appreciated...

Comment: Is it SublimeText you are talking about?

Comment: Yes that and, if possible we can be inclusive of Notepad++, VSCode etc. let's say nearly all popular editors that support PCRE Regex flavour

Comment: But Notepad++ regex flavor is Boost (it is based on PCRE though), and VSCode uses three different regex engines in different places. Only SublimeText from these three uses PCRE.

Comment: I guess `(\R){2,}(?!\R*\[[^][]*]$)` => `$1` might work for NPP and SublimeText. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6iFchr/1).

Comment: Ok then let's keep Sublime Text in mind, as I use it as main editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Notepad++ and Sublime Text, you can use

*Find What*: `(\R){2,}(?!\R*\[[^][]*]$)`
*Replace With*: `$1`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6iFchr/1). *Details*:

- `(\R){2,}` - two or more line break sequences (the last one captured is saved in Group 1 memory buffer)
- `(?!\R*\[[^][]*]$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are

  - `\R*` - zero or more line break sequences
  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]` - a `]` char
  - `$` - end of a line.

In Visual Studio Code, this regex needs tweaking a bit:

```
(\n){2,}(?!\n*\[[^\][]*\]$)
```

Here, `\n` matches any line ending (no need for `\R`), and the literal square brackets needs escaping (only the `[` inside a character class does not need escaping).

Answer (score 1):

Cheating and copying from Wiktor answer,
This code gave me the result in my editor as was intended ...

Find:`(?!\n*\[)(\n){2,}`
Replace with:`$1`